# how do i disable onTouch()?

Tags: android, android-view, touch-event

I am trying to disable onTouch() when my LoadPreview().execute is being launched because if the user taps on the button which triggles my LoadPreview(), there will be duplicate preview buttons. So I want to disable onTouch() during the loading process.

is there a way?

This is my ontouch method:

```
@Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    switch(arg1.getAction())
                    {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        adapter.clear();
                        new LoadPreview().execute();
                    break;
                    } 

                    return true;
                }   

             }
                );

             }
```

this is my loadpreview()

```
/**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadPreview extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * getting preview url and then load them
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


            // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_magazine, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        mag = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MAGAZINE);

                        for (int i = 0; i < mag.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = mag.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String magazinePreview = c.getString(TAG_MAGAZINE_PREVIEW);

                            previewList.add(magazinePreview);
                        }                   
                    } 
                    else {

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            for (int a = 0; a <= previewList.size(); a++)
            {           
                if(pos == a)
                {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json1 = jParser.makeHttpRequest(previewList.get(a), "GET", param);

            // CHECKING OF JSON RESPONSE
            Log.d("All guide: ", json.toString());

            try {
                preview = json1.getJSONArray(TAG_PREVIEWS);

                for (int i = 0; i < preview.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = preview.getJSONObject(i);

                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                    previewImagesList.add(image);
                    //System.out.println(guideList);
                }   

                // STOP THE LOOP
                break;

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            }

            }


            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

        /**
         *  Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
        * */            
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
```

onItemClick method:

```
coverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            adapter.clear();
            File sdCard1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir1 = new File (sdCard1.getAbsolutePath() + "/Futsing/issue"+issueNumber+"/"); 

                    /** IF FILE EXISTS **/
                    if(dir1.exists())
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(CoverFlowExample.this, Reader.class);
                        intent.putExtra("issue", issueNumber);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_INTENT_CODE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(process==false)
                        {
                            new LoadPreview().execute();
                            process = true;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            process = false;
                        }
                    }
        }

    }

);
```

Comment: see my answer and feel free for any comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do as Gabe said.
You can also do the thing like here i have explained.
1. define one boolean like:

```
private boolean process = false;
```

1. Override the method like onPreExecution in the AsyncTask.
2. Put boolean on the above method an define its value to true.

   process = true;
3. Now, onPostExecution method put this:

   process = false
4. And also implement your onTouch method like below:

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   if(process==false){

       switch(arg1.getAction())
       {
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              adapter.clear();
              new LoadPreview().execute();
              break;
       } 

       return true;
       }   
       else{
         return false;
   }

   }
   ```

   );

** FOR onItenClick **

You can use below code for onItemClick to work as you want.

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {

       if(process==false)
       {

        adapter.clear();
        File sdCard1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir1 = new File (sdCard1.getAbsolutePath() + "/Futsing/issue"+issueNumber+"/"); 

                /** IF FILE EXISTS **/
                if(dir1.exists())
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setClass(CoverFlowExample.this, Reader.class);
                    intent.putExtra("issue", issueNumber);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, GET_INTENT_CODE);
                }
                else
                {

                        new LoadPreview().execute();


                }
          }else{
                // nothing to do here it means the process is running
          }
    }

}
```

Comment: for onItemClick, i did process = true instead of return true since the return type is not a boolean. when i tested it, as i simultaneously press the preview button (before the data actually finish loading), it displays duplicate images.

Comment: please put your onItemClick code so i can give you update of that also

Comment: Welcome my friend. And you can upvote it so it can help other also.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag.  Put a boolean allowTouch in your class.  Default it to true.  When you want to stop touches set it to false.  When you're ready to take touches again, set it to true.  Change your onTouch method so that it only runs the code in there now if allowTouch == true.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `boolean` flag to check if data is loading to prevent duplicate calls.

Declare a global `boolean`, for example: `boolean loadingData;`

Then, in your `onTouch()` method, set the `loadingPreview = true;`

And finally, in the `onPostExecute()` method of your AsyncTask `loadingPreview`, toggle the `loadingPreview` to `loadingPreview = false;`

This will ensure no duplicate class will be made to fetch data while it is still doing so. And toggling the state will ensure the app will be ready again.

EDIT: Don't forget to check the state in the `onTouch()` method before calling the AyncTask `loadingPreview`

```
if (loadingPreview == false) {
    new LoadPreview().execute();
}
```